# Logging with Serilog in MassTransit

Tags: serilog, masstransit

I've tried to use `MassTransit.SerilogIntegration` nuget, but it looks like its last version is 5.5.6. I'm using MassTransit 7.1.4, and when I've installed this Serilog nuget, I got an exception that it can't find the `ILog` interface. Is there any way to use Serilog with the current version of MassTransit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MassTransit uses `ILoggerFactory` from the container, so as long as the logging provider is configured and part of the container, it will be resolved and used. It doesn't matter if it is Serilog, or Microsoft Extensions Logging.

[This sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ForkJoint/blob/master/src/ForkJoint.Api/Program.cs#L19) uses Serilog – in fact almost all of my samples use it.

This can be configured at the `Hosting` level:

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseSerilog((host, log) =>
{
    if (host.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
        log.MinimumLevel.Information();
    else
        log.MinimumLevel.Debug();

    log.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning);
    log.WriteTo.Console();
})
```

Or at the program level:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("JobService", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .UseSerilog();
```

These all use the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` NuGet package. There are no longer log-specific packages for MassTransit.